# weak-topology of a topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a topological vector space and $E'$ seperating on $E$. The $E'$-topology is called the  weak topology on E, which I will denote with $\mathcal{T}_{w}$. Then is $(E,\mathcal{T}_{w})= E_{w}$ a locally convex space whose dual is $E'$.
If $E$ is infinite-dimensional then the weak topology is really weaker than the original one, but they can coincide: $(E_{w})_{w} = E_{w}$. The last statement should follow from the following theorem:

Suppose $E$ is a vector space and $\tilde{E}$ is a separating space of linear functionals on $E$. Then the $\tilde{E}$-topology $\tilde{\tau}$ makes $E$ into a locally convex space whose dual is $\tilde{E}$.

I don't really understand how this theorem implies $(E_{w})_{w} = E_{w}$. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weak topology is the coarsest topology making every element of the dual continuous, hence it is determined by $E'$. Therefore, $(E_\sigma)'=E'$ implies $(E_\sigma)_\sigma=E_\sigma $.